# Failure instantiating web-service client on xcode app upload

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I'm using XCode 4.0.2 to upload my iPhone app to the iTunes app store but get the following error messages:

```
Failure instantiating web-service client
An exception has occurred: Unable to open url: https://contentdelivery.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZLabelService.woa/ws/MZITunesProducerService?wsdl
Could not connect to Apple's web service
Unable to authenticate the package: 450416349.itmsp
```

I've got the latest Java version (1.6) and have double checked the network settings in the Java preferences.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got to the bottom of it. Running a TCP dump on our firewall discovered that some (but not all) of the requests that XCode made were using the configured proxy, and others were not.

We allowed the proxy to be bypassed completely to test and it all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Application Loader? Try that and see if it works. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, but the exact same problem occurs